# Adding PNG to UIImageView with code looks terrible compared to adding it directly in the NIB

Tags: uiimageview, png, imagenamed

How do I get the image added to the UIImageView to look the same when added in code as when I add it directly in the NIB?

I have a 5 of clubs picture, in the NIB file I use the Image drop down to select the 5 of clubs picture from the resources.  The 5 of clubs looks perfect.

When I use the same resource to add the image to the UIImageVIew using code the image looks terrible.  Looks like a terrible resize job.

Here is the code I am using to add the image to the UIImageView.

```
 uiimg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5clubs.png"];
```

Comment: Could you show us images of the two?

Comment: OK, I solved the problem.
Seems I needed to Clean the project and recompile for it to pick up the new image.  I had previously a HUGE image with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to Clean the project and recompile for it to pick up the new image. I had previously a HUGE image with the same name.